# how to make v-flex responsive

Tags: javascript, flexbox, vuetify.js

I have this code

`<v-layout align-center justify-center row fill-height>
    <v-flex sm6 xs12></v-flex>
    <v-flex sm6 xs12></v-flex>
</v-layout>`

But it is not making width 100% on mobile as I would expect. 
I would like to make a 50% with on `sm` sizes and 100% on `xs` sizes. Like it does bootstrap.

How to archive that with Vuetify?

Comment: Please reproduce on [codepen](https://template.vuetifyjs.com).

Comment: Here it is on https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oaNoxG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.
Needed to add **wrap** to a layout `<v-layout wrap>` and that fixed it.